# Get information sent from inside event (event.data) JQuery/Websocket

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, websocket

I want to get the Status from inside the event.
here is the code that I'm sending:

```
wsUser.send('{"Username" : 212000362,"Status" :'+status+',"email" :"'+email+'"}');
```

and here is the receiving part:

```
wsUser.onmessage = function(event) {
console.log(event.data);
var tmp = event.data.status;
alert(tmp)
console.log(tmp);
}
```

event.data.status is not working, its not retrieving the value, when done it returns: **undefined** in the console log and as an alert.

Any ideas?
Thanks!!

Comment: It is **undefined**, not "undifined". About your question: you pass String, not an Object. Try `wsUser.send({ "Username": 212000362, "Status": status, "email": email});` instead.

Comment: hello, thanks for the reply. I did as you told me, but still i got: undefined

Comment: Well, maybe the problem is that I don't know what this `.send()` and `.onmessage` is all about. Try your original string version and `var data = JSON.parse(event.data); var tmp = data.status;`

Comment: its the websocket API, its a standard...

Comment: I didn't say that it's something exotic - I just don't know what it is. Nevertheless, does `JSON.parse()` help or it is time to read docs about websocket?

Answer (score 2):

If the code you posted is correct, and there are no typos, then your problem is the way you retrieve the status:

```
event.data.status
```

This should be:

```
event.data.Status
```

Notice the uppercase "S". Javascript is case sensitive. There is no lowercase status. That's why you get the "undefined".